# Can metamagic feats be applied to Apocalypse from the Sky?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, metamagic

Apocalypse from the Sky is a 9th level spell from the Book of Vile Darkness. Epic level rules allow for spell slots higher than 9th level, so assuming one had access to those, could such feats be applied? This would make an already powerful spell even more dangerous (example: widen spell). But I can’t see a rule that would forbid this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes.

There's nothing special about Apocalypse from the Sky that prevents applying metamagic feats to it.  The only difficulty is that it's a 9th level spell, so metamagic feats that require a higher-level spell slot will be difficult to apply.

There are several ways to circumvent this difficulty:

- As you've mentioned in the question, the epic feat [Improved Spell Capacity](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/feats.htm#improvedSpellCapacity) can give you spell slots higher than 9th level, which you could fill with metamagic'ed Apocalypse from the Sky.
- Certain metamagic feats, like Sanctum Spell (*Complete Arcane*, p. 82) don't require a higher level spell slot.  These can be freely applied to Apocalypse from the Sky.
- Some feats, classes, and items, like Arcane Thesis (*Player's Handbook II*, p. 74), Incantatrix (*Player's Guide to Faerun*, p. 61), or [metamagic rods](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rods.htm#metamagicRods) can reduce or ignore the increased spell slot cost of metamagic.  Some forms of this ability have a minimum spell slot adjustment of +1, but not all (Arcane Thesis only says that a spell "cannot be reduced to below its original level with the use of this feat").
- Some metamagic feats, like Sudden Maximize (*Complete Arcane*, p. 83) have use-per-day restrictions instead of requiring higher level spell slots.  These can be used on Apocalypse from the Sky without issue.
- Some abilities allow you to pay metamagic costs using alternative resources, like the Divine Metamagic (*Complete Divine*, p. 80) or Metamagic Song (*Races of Stone*, p. 142) mentioned in [KRyan's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180502/can-metamagic-feats-be-applied-to-apocalypse-from-the-sky/180504#180504).

In short, the only thing that makes applying metamagic to Apocalypse from the Sky difficult is the fact that it's a 9th level spell, and there are many ways to solve that problem.

Comment: There was also a way to spend turn undead uses instead of in Rea spell slot level if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 3):

There’s nothing special about *apocalypse from the sky*; you can use metamagic on it the same as you can use metamagic on anything else. There are metamagic feats that don’t affect spell level (e.g. Energy Substitution or Searing Spell), there are ways to decrease the costs of metamagic feats (e.g. incantatrix, Arcane Thesis) or to pay them through alternate means (e.g. Divine Metamagic, Metamagic Song), and as you say, in Epic play, there is Improved Spell Capacity to get 10th-or-higher-level spell slots. So long as you can pay the cost of the the metamagic, you can apply it to *apocalypse from the sky* or any other spell for that matter.¹

1. <sub>Barring the spells from Epic Spellcasting, which use an entirely separate system.</sub>